# Compact imbedding - reference request

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for reference to the following imbedding theorem:

**Theorem**

For any $s>1/2$ fractional Sobolev space $W^{s}_2(0,1)$ imbeds compactly into $C([0,1])$.

I know how to prove it but I need the reference for my article.

Thanks.

Comment: These useless repetitive edits by a single person are really boring...

Answer (score 1):

See:

[*Sobolev Spaces* by Robert A. Adams, John J. F. Fournier](http://books.google.com.cy/books/about/Sobolev_Spaces.html?id=R5A65Koh-EoC&redir_esc=y)